# Getting height of children elements in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Inside a React component, I want to be able to calculate the combined height of each of my child containers, in this case, the three h3 elements, so that I can calculate the exact height of my parent div when animating the transition of its height. I have seen examples of this with basic js as well as using component mounting methods, but how do I get the height of these elements using just JavaScript?

```js
class Div extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Description One</h3>
        <h3>Description Two</h3>
        <h3>Description Three</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Div />, app);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What are "ES6 children"? Anyway, it's not usually worth it to try to do this. Just animate `max-height`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In React, to manipulate the DOM, you'll want to use Refs: [React Docs - Adding a Ref to a DOM element](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element).

In your example, for your `<h3>` elements, you'd do something like this:

```
    <h3 ref={(elem) => this.Line1 = elem}>Description One</h3>
    <h3 ref={(elem) => this.Line2 = elem}>Description Two</h3>
    <h3 ref={(elem) => this.Line3 = elem}>Description Three</h3>
```

Once you have a Ref to an element, you can use methods & properties of any DOM element on it. For instance, to get its height, you can use [Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight):

```
calcHeight() {
  return this.Line1.clientHeight + this.Line2.clientHeight + this.Line3.clientHeight;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bu725co3/)

Comment: Thanks Jaxx! However, when I try this method, I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined". I get this error when trying to return the calcHeight() or just {this.Line1.clientHeight}, even when I bind to the constructor. [Please see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt7n5mmu/), thanks!

Comment: @Jimmy Hmm that's odd. Hard for me to check as you linked the wrong JSFiddle, but see the following, which is almost verbatim the code I gave you (only added passing the result to state to print it out on the page): http://jsfiddle.net/tda6kd9c/. As you can see, working as intended.

Comment: Thanks @Jaxx. I'm not sure what was wrong, but the additional fiddle helped, and it looks like addint `this.calcHeight()` to the `componentDidMount` helps.

Comment: Changed my career. I had no idea about this capability.